# React chars to HTML encode?

Tags: xss, attack-prevention, encoding, react

I've observed that React can HTML encode specific characters to prevent XSS vulnerabilities in certain contexts. For instance, consider the following code in **App.jsx**:

```
function App() {
    const XSSProblematicChars = "><'\"()&:`";

    return (
        <>
            <h4>Displayed: {XSSProblematicChars}</h4>
            <img src={XSSProblematicChars}/>
        </>
    );
}
```

The corresponding HTML output would be:

```
<h4>Displayed: &gt;&lt;'"()&amp;:`</h4>
<img src="><'&quot;()&amp;:`">
```

As demonstrated, HTML encoding varies depending on the context. For instance:

1. In the **h4** element, `<`, `>`, and `&` characters are encoded.
2. In the **src** attribute of the **img** element, `"` and `&` characters are encoded.

However, it's important to note that this encoding alone may not provide comprehensive protection against XSS attacks. To illustrate, consider the following **App.jsx** code. If the anchor element is clicked, the document's content can be altered using an XSS payload:

```
function App() {
    const XSSPayload =
        "javascript:eval(atob('ZG9jdW1lbnQuYm9keS5pbm5lckhUTUw9JzxoMSBzdHlsZT0idGV4dC1hbGlnbjogY2VudGVyOyBwb3NpdGlvbjogYWJzb2x1dGU7IHRvcDogNTAlOyBsZWZ0OiA1MCU7IHRyYW5zZm9ybTogdHJhbnNsYXRlKC01MCUsIC01MCUpOyI+ISEhIEhBQ0tFRCAhISE8L2gxPic7'))";

    return (
        <>
            <a href={XSSPayload}>Click Me to Trigger XSS</a>
        </>
    );
}
```

This occurs because React fails to HTML encode the `:` character, allowing the use of `javascript:` syntax to trigger XSS.

To address this issue, I aim to create a function that will HTML encode all problematic characters in user input displayed on the frontend. Are there any other characters, like `:`, that React might have overlooked when encoding for HTML output?

Answer (score 0):

React does not protect against XSS when using JSX data binding syntax ({}) in HTML attributes [1].

For HTML, the recommendation is to do this:

```
import purify from "dompurify";
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html:purify.sanitize(data) }} />
```

I would recommend to use DOMPurify and not try to develop your own solution if you don't have a good reason for it.

If you still want to develop your own solution, [2] describes a safe way of encoding HTML Attributes:

> HTML Attribute Encoding Encoding Mechanism: Encode all characters with
> the HTML Entity &#xHH; format, including spaces, where HH represents
> the hexadecimal value of the character in Unicode. For example, A
> becomes A. All alphanumeric characters (letters A to Z, a to z,
> and digits 0 to 9) remain unencoded.

Even if you do so, there are HTML attributes (e.g. onClick) where it is dangerous to inject user provided data. They are listed in [3] too.

[1] https://snyk.io/blog/10-react-security-best-practices/ 
[2] https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#output-encoding-rules-summary 
[3] https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#output-encoding-for-html-attribute-contexts